# Expectation in cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have this CDF:

$$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x<-4.5$} \\
0.1,  & \text{if $-4.5\leq x<3$} \\
0.3,  & \text{if $3\leq x<6$} \\
0.6,  & \text{if $6\leq x<10$} \\
1,  & \text{if $x\geq 10$}
\end{cases}$$

The questions involved were:

1. Calculate P(X=0)

I just said it was 0, because 0 is in the middle of an interval

2. Calculate P(X=3)

I said it was 0.2, because 3 is the start of an interval, so I just subtracted all the intervals before it before it's own interval

3. Find the expected value of X

This is where I'm a little lost. I tried looking up how to do it online, and tried the integral method where I sum up the integrals of each range, but the answer I got for that was wrong. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there...1 and 2 are correct. To calculate the expectation observe that your rv is discrete and it is defined in

$$\{-4.5;3;6;10\}$$

with probabilities that you are able to calculate...thus the expectation is simply

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\Sigma_i x_i p(x_i)$$

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=-4.5\times0.1+3\times 0.2+6\times0.3+10\times0.4=5.95$$

No integral is needed in this case.

Comment: Oh my god thank you, I think I'm getting you. I'm just stuck on one part now. So, we already have P(X=3) is 0.2, and P(X=-4.5) is 0.1. I calculated P(X=6) and got it to be 0.2 as well. Now I just need P(X=10), right? I'm having a little trouble calculating that :(

Comment: @Ben $1-0.6$ , the same you did for the other $x_i$ but $ P(6)=0.3$. If my answer has been useful you can mark it as accepted

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!